# Jquery Joyride - not working with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use Jquery-Joyride - http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin, but I can not get it to work with Jquery Mobile.  As soon as I add the standard JQM  tags the help windows will no longer display.

Here is what I'm trying:
.....

```
<ol id="joyRideTipContent">
  <li data-id="numero2" data-text="Next" class="custom">
    <h2>Stop #1</h2>
    <p>You can control all the details for you tour stop. Any valid HTML will work inside of Joyride.</p>
  </li>
```

....

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {      
    $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({postStepCallback : function (index, tip){
      if (index == 2) {
        $(this).joyride('set_li', false, 1);
      }
    }});
  });
</script>
```

.....

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="four columns">
    <img src="280x120.gif"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="eight columns">
    <h3 id="numero2">Customize Each Stop Along the Way</h3>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

.....

Everything works fine with the code above.  However, as soon as I add the JQM specific  tag, the help windows no longer appear.

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-home" data-dom-cache="false" id="home">
```

I'm not sure how to get this working.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: document ready or window load can't be used to initialize a jQuery plugin inside a jQuery Mobile page, you shoud use appropriate jQuery Mobile page event, in your case pageshow. Read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is **`window load`**, like **`document ready`** it will not work correctly with **`jQuery Mobile`**.

Instead you should use this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride();
});
```

where **`#index`** is an id of your page.

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/sdwXt/

It was made from an official **DEMO** example.

One last thing, before you go further with **`jQuery Mobile`** read my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Comment: I can get this all working, however for some reason I have to call  $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride(); twice to get it to start.  I see in your JSfiddle you don't have to do this, but for some reason I can't get it to work any other way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If it is not a problem, mail me your page and I will take a look at it. My mail can be found inside my profile.

Comment: Thanks, just sent it over.

Comment: user2175057 this should autostart joyride so you don't have to twice
$("#instructions").joyride({autoStart:true});

Comment: @Gajotres Im trying to use it with `jQuery.when` but it only shows when I do `$('#joyRideTipContent').joyride();` twice

Answer (score 0):

If you're having to call the joyride() function twice, revert back to version 2.0.3, which can be found at https://github.com/zurb/joyride/releases - I tried a few version and it's the only one without any obvious bugs!